How to use Pyomo for adding constraints on the output of a function
I am currently working on developing a specialized solver aimed at tuning the hyperparameters of a SARIMAX (Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average with eXogenous regressors) model. The primary objective of this project is to ensure that the model maintains its accuracy above a predetermined threshold. To achieve this, I am utilizing Pyomo, a powerful optimization modeling tool, as my solver to help identify the optimal values for the hyperparameters required to meet this accuracy criterion.
The focus of my efforts is to generate outputs for two critical performance metrics: train_r2 and test_r2. By ensuring that both of these metrics exceed a specific range, I can confidently determine whether the selected hyperparameters are effective enough to construct a robust and reliable predictive model. The R² score, which indicates the proportion of variance in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variables, is crucial for evaluating the model's performance.
Although the SARIMAX model is being created successfully, I am facing issues with the satisfaction of the constraints I have set. I have attempted various solvers, including glpk, ipopt, and cbc, to find a suitable solution. Despite the output indicating that a successful solution has been found, it appears that the constraints are still being violated
I am currently investigating potential causes for this problem, which may include reevaluating the bounds of the hyperparameters, examining the formulation of the objective function, or adjusting the constraints to ensure they are correctly implemented. The ultimate goal is to refine the hyperparameter tuning process so that I can achieve a SARIMAX model that not only performs well in terms of accuracy but also meets the predefined thresholds for both training and testing datasets.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.environ import *
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# Step 1: Create a synthetic time series dataset
np.random.seed(42)
n = 120  # Length of time series data

# Generate a seasonal pattern with trend and noise
time = np.arange(n)
seasonal_pattern = 10 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * time / 12)
trend = 0.1 * time
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
data = 20 + trend + seasonal_pattern + noise

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value'])
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', periods=n, freq='D')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Step 2: Split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train, test = df.iloc[:train_size], df.iloc[train_size:]

# Step 3: Define the Pyomo model
model = ConcreteModel()

# Define integer variables for SARIMA parameters
model.p = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.d = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.q = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.P = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.D = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.Q = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, 10), initialize=1)
model.seasonality = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(2, 12), initialize=2)
print("Displaying P value ",model.p.display())

# Define parameters to store R² scores
model.train_r2 = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.test_r2 = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.test_train_sum = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)


# Step 4: Define a function to fit SARIMAX and calculate R² values
def sarima_r2_model(p, d, q, P, D, Q, seasonality):
    try:
        # Fit SARIMAX model with the given parameters
        model = SARIMAX(
            train['value'],
            order=(p, d, q),
            seasonal_order=(P, D, Q, seasonality),
            enforce_stationarity=False,
            enforce_invertibility=False
        )
        results = model.fit(disp=False)

        # Calculate R² on both train and test sets
        train_pred = results.predict(start=train.index[0], end=train.index[-1])
        test_pred = results.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])
        train_r2_value = r2_score(train['value'], train_pred)
        test_r2_value = r2_score(test['value'], test_pred)
        return train_r2_value, test_r2_value
    except:
        print("========== If model fitting fails, return low R² values")
        return -10, -10

# Define objective to maximize sum of R² scores
def objective_rule(m):
    p = int(m.p.value)
    d = int(m.d.value)
    q = int(m.q.value)
    P = int(m.P.value)
    D = int(m.D.value)
    Q = int(m.Q.value)
    seasonality = int(m.seasonality.value)
    m.train_r2.value, m.test_r2.value = sarima_r2_model(p, d, q, P, D, Q, seasonality)
    
    # Store R² values in model variables for constraints

    print("train_r2_value ==========",m.train_r2.value)
    print("test_r2_value ==========",m.test_r2.value)
    model.test_train_sum = m.train_r2.value + m.test_r2.value 
    return model.test_train_sum


# Set objective function
model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=maximize)



# Step 5: Add constraints for minimum R² threshold
r2_threshold = 0.8
model.train_r2_constraint = Constraint(expr=model.train_r2 >= r2_threshold)
model.test_r2_constraint = Constraint(expr=model.test_r2>=r2_threshold)


# Step 6: Solve the optimization problem with a suitable solver
solver = SolverFactory('cbc',executable="/usr/bin/cbc")  # Choose solver like 'cbc' or 'glpk' if available


results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
print(results.write())
print(results.solver.status)
print("optimal",results.solver.termination_condition)

print("# will show you the evaluation of the OBJ function")
model.objective.display()  
print(model.objective.expr()) 

# Step 7: Retrieve the best parameters
best_params = {
    'p': int(model.p.value),
    'd': int(model.d.value),
    'q': int(model.q.value),
    'P': int(model.P.value),
    'D': int(model.D.value),
    'Q': int(model.Q.value),
    'seasonality': int(model.seasonality.value)
}
print("Optimized parameters:", best_params)

# Step 8: Train the final model with optimized parameters
best_model = SARIMAX(
    train['value'],
    order=(best_params['p'], best_params['d'], best_params['q']),
    seasonal_order=(best_params['P'], best_params['D'], best_params['Q'], best_params['seasonality']),
    enforce_stationarity=False,
    enforce_invertibility=False
)
best_results = best_model.fit(disp=False)

# Step 9: Final evaluation on train and test sets
train_pred = best_results.predict(start=train.index[0], end=train.index[-1])
test_pred = best_results.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])

print("Final Train R²:", r2_score(train['value'], train_pred))
print("Final Test R²:", r2_score(test['value'], test_pred))


A couple of things as this is a first post...
This question (and future questions) needs a bit more focus to get good answers on this site.  Large questions (like this one) that "I built this large thing and something isn't working" tend to not get as much traction as ones that focus on a more specific issue (with reproducible code).  You have code (good), but not much focus.
The problem here is that you are not using pyomo correctly.  Pyomo is a framework to build a math model, which is then handed over to a solver separately (you state in your question that pyomo is a solver--that is not correct, and may be part of the misuse.)
So, with that, pyomo needs to form a set of equations in terms of the variables, which are unknown and send it to a solver to chew on.  You are mistakenly passing in a SARIMAX model (problem #1) and also attempting to definitize the variable values in the objective (problem #2).
Perhaps a concept that will help guide you in this is looking for frameworks that are a "black box solver" where you can hand it any arbitrary function and let it evaluate and try to better the outcome--that's a different framework than pyomo.  I believe there is one in scikit.  YMMV.
